# How to get text, using Selenium Python XPATH

Tags: python, selenium

I try to find and get element(text), using

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhlfT.png)

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="t3_9kxrv6"]/div/div/div[3]/span/h2')
```

If I print it, I get:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2c3430395624712686d8cbfe1824c18e", element="0.06192509533309787-1")>
```

and I want:  "The problems of a dutchman in China."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want just .text

So, use this

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="t3_9kxrv6"]/div/div/div[3]/span/h2').text
```