# Python Selenium - can't get elements by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
    <table class="wikitable" style="float: right;">
    <caption>Current UTC
    </caption>
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>**January 26, 2020 01:13:27 (UTC) –** <span class="plainlinks" id="purgelink"><span class="nowrap"><a class="external text" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Coordinated_Universal_Time&amp;action=purge">Refresh</a></span></span>

</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I just need to get the date. I tried:

```py
utc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/text()')
```

ERROR:

> invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes?

Comment: yes. still doesn't work =(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text, using Selenium Python XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632136/how-to-get-text-using-selenium-python-xpath)

Comment: `utc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td').text`

Comment: Thanks Nick! It actually solved my issue. Albeit it has the refresh link text there but that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed version of the xpath you are tying to get.

```
utc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td')
print(utc.text)
```

But above will include the text of the "Refresh" link.  To only get the date you might try:

```
utc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td')
utc_trim = utc.get_attribute('innerHTML').split('<')[0]
print(utc_trim)
```

To help with page load timing issues you may want to do something like below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

utc = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td')))
utc_trim = utc.get_attribute('innerHTML').split('<')[0]
print(utc_trim)
```