# How can i get car names by using driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'') with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, find, element

From [this link](https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?dam=0&isSearchRequest=true&ms=19000%3B20%3B%3B&ref=quickSearch&sb=rel&vc=Car), I want to get all of the car names as a list but
only thing i can get is this: ------------> Car name is : []

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="headline-block u-margin-bottom-9"><span class="sponsored-badge">Sponsored</span><span class="h3 u-text-break-word">Opel Omega</span></div>
```

Here is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


service = Service(executable_path='C:/Users/Wiveda/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/chromedriver.exe')

import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies'

my_cookies = dict(cookies_are='Cookies parameter use to send cookies to the server')
r = requests.get(url, cookies=my_cookies)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))


options = Options()
options.headless = True  # hide GUI
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")  # set window size to native GUI size
options.add_argument("start-maximized")  # ensure window is full-screen

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])


driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(
    "https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?dam=0&isSearchRequest=true&ms=19000%3B20%3B%3B&ref=quickSearch&sb=rel&vc=Car")
print("Application title is :", driver.title)
print("Application url is ", driver.current_url)
carname = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='h3 u-text-break-word']")
print("Car name is :", carname)

driver.quit()
```

I get stuck
Plese help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an error in the XPath expression you are using. On my browser I am able to extract the list of car names using the following XPath:

```
"//span[@class='h3 u-text-break-word']".
```

EDIT

The XPath will give you a list of elements. For each element you can access the "text" attribute as in the following ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632272/19406735)):

```py
carname = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='h3 u-text-break-word']")
for name in carname:
    print(name.text)
```

Let me know if it is good for you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this below lines of code from image
[image]